# jQuery Mobile $.mobile.changePage()

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have a problem regarding $.mobile.changePage(); I have this select control that serves as a Jump To Page controller. The code is written below:

```
$( document ).one( "pagechange", function() {
    $("#jumptopage").bind("change", function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.mobile.changePage( "http://localhost/mchild/dashboard/videos/all/20/" + val, {reloadPage : "true",transition: "fade", allowSamePageTransition : "true"} );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now this code works the first time; but as I jump to another page it causes jQuery Mobile to jitter back and forth to current page and previous page that was loaded before, or in other cases the bind() wont work anymore.

I tried to log the activity by adding

```
console.log('i was triggered')
```

inside the $( document ).one().... right after the bind statement and it still fires except for the bind.

I'm not sure if I did something wrong... please help...

Comment: have you try `$("#jumptopage").on( ... )` or `$('body').on('#jumptopage', 'change', ... )` ?

Comment: yup tried those as well, same thing...

Comment: I've identified the problem. The jitter happens when you use the `<select name="select-choice-a" id="jumptopage" data-theme="a" data-native-menu="false">` with this option **data-native-menu="false"**. As when the Custom menu closes it tries to reload the previous page, but beforehand we already activated the **changePage** function call and viola! double request and whichever gets the result last wins the game. I just stopped using the custom select menu for now.